# Count all numbers up to X that are divisible by at least two of their digits

Tags: algorithms, enumeration, counting, mathematical-programming

I want to count how may numbers are there in range [1,X] which are divisible by at least two of their digits, different and >1. I found a sequence on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A187516), but this will take lot of time to generate all such numbers as X can be $10^{18}$. How to do this efficiently?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Can you please post the original source of the question. It shouldn't be from any live coding contest.

Comment: Original source of a question is  my grandfather's old  book

Comment: 1. It would be good to edit the question to add proper attribution: title & author of the old book.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  You should credit the source of problems.  2. You should also tell us your thoughts and what progress you've made (we expect you to spend a significant amount of time trying to solve it on your own before asking here, and show us in the question what approaches you've considered and why you rejected them).  3. What does "different and >1" mean?  What is that supposed to modify?  Please edit the question to clarify & address the feedback.

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1847779/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. Also posted on https://www.codechef.com/JULY16/problems/WORKCHEF.  This is a live contest problem..

Answer (score 2):

Note: You are not asked to give a list of all numbers. You are asked how many there are. A simpler question: How many integers from 1 to $10^{18}-1$ are divisible by both 2 and 3? You can figure this out without giving a list of all those numbers. It's actually quite easy, so figure this out first. That's just to get you to understand the idea, and to get you warmed up. And this being computer science, expect to write some code :-)

Now slightly more difficult: How many numbers contain the digits 2 and 3, and are divisible by both 2 and 3? That's not trivial, but you should be able to figure it out. Then the same for 2 and 4, ... , 2 and 9, ..., 8 and 9. Then add up the numbers.

The problem is that you counted some numbers twice. If a number has digits 2, 3, 4 and is divisible by 2, 3, and 4, then you counted it under (2, 3), under (2, 4) and under (3, 4), that is you counted it 3 times instead of once. So subtract twice the count of these numbers. And then the same for (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), ... up to (7, 8, 9).

Now numbers with digits 2, 3, 4, 5 and divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5: Any of these numbers, you counted under (2, 3), (2, 4), ..., (4, 5), a total of six times. You subtracted it twice under (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), and (3, 4, 5); total 8 times, so you counted it -2 times instead of +1 times. So add the count of these numbers three times. Same for the other combinations.

And you go on like that. It's a lot of work, but not too bad and should be doable in a few seconds CPU time.

Comment: I got your point but its lot of work. My main question involves counting such numbers which are divisible by at least 1,2,3..9 of their digits. I think this method will require lot of work. I hope there exist a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Counting all such numbers less than X can actually be done quite easily in $O (\log x)$ steps with a rather large constant, which would let us find the count for large values like X = $10^{100}$ quite easily. We use the fact that we can determine which factors < 10 a number x has if we know x (modulo 2520).

For each subset S of { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } and for every r, 0 ≤ r < 2520, and for various values Y and Z, we determine how many numbers 0 ≤ x < Y and how many numbers 0 ≤ x < Z where x = r (modulo 2520) have all the digits in the set S, and no others except 0 and 1. These numbers can be stored in two table of 256 x 2520 = 645,120 elements each.

We build such tables first for Y = 10 and for Z = X (modulo Y); that is quite easy because most table entries are zero, except the entries for ( {}, 0), ( {}, 1), ( {2}, 2), ... ( {9}, 9) have a count of 1 when Z = 10, and fewer entries when Z = X (modulo 10).

We then build tables with Y = $10^k$ and Z = X (modulo Y), up to and including the first k where $Y = 10^k > X$ and therefore Z = X. We build the table for Y by adding a digit from 0 to 9 in front of each number in the table for Y/10 that we built just before; if the previous table had a count c for the set S and some r, then we add c in the new table to the entries (S, r), (S, (r + $10^{k-1}$ modulo 2520), (S + {2}, (r + $2 · 10^{k-1}$ modulo 2520), ..., (S + {9}, (r + $9 · 10^{k-1}$ modulo 2520). For the table for Z, we only process some digits like this, and one digit uses the previous table for Z = X modulo ($10^{k-1}$).

For example, if X = 123,456, we build tables for Y = 10, Z = 6, then Y = 100, Z = 56, then Y = 1000, Z = 456, and so on. Each table is a few million operations, and we do this $\log_{10} X$ times.

Once we have the table for Z = X, we add up all the counts for entries where r is divisible by all elements of S. So the total time is O ($\log X$), but with a huge constant. If X is truly large then adding numbers is not an elementary operation anymore, so we would have another factor of log X for multi-precision addition, for a total of O ($\log^2 X$).

To give a bit more of an example: For example, the number 2 < 10 has the set of digits { 2 } and is 2 (modulo 2520). Therefore the entry ( {2}, 2) gets a count of 1.

In the second round, we add digits 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 in front of the digit 2. That gives the numbers 02, 12, 22, 32, 42, .., 92. The sets of digits are {2}, {2}, {2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, ..., {2, 9} because we ignore the digits 0 and 1, and 22 still has only the digit 2. The entries ( {2}, 2), ({2}, 12), ({2}, 22), ({2,3}, 32),..., ({ 2, 9}, 92) will get a count of 1.

Since the table has about 600,000 entries, it will take quite a few rounds until the counts grow big, but when Y = $10^{18}$, the counts will be roughly around $10^{12}$. So each round is considerable but not excessive work, but as Y gets larger, it doesn't get more work.

Now lets say you have built the tables to the end, and you have say an entry ( {2, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 30) with a count of 12,590. Just an example. If you have a number x with x = 30 (modulo 2520), then the divisors of 30 that interest us are 2, 3, 5, 6. Each such x has divisors 2, 3, 5, 6 and no others up to 9 (we don't care about the divisor 1). Three of these are in the set {2, 4, 5, 6, 7} so all the 12,590 numbers count towards your total.

The same (with the set {2, 4, 5, 6, 7}) happens with the modulo 32 (divisors 2, 4), 35 (divisors 5, 7), 36 (divisors 2, 4, 6), 40 (divisors 2, 4, 5), 42 (divisors, 2, 6, 7), etc. but not with the other moduli (31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43 etc. ). So you add the counts for some moduli, not for others.

Comment: I got your point. Its a nice idea though. Can you please explain me with the help of simple example how to build tables and use previous tables to build new tables.

Comment: For  Y = 10 and for Z = X (modulo Y); will entry ({0,2,3}, 2) have count of 1? I am bit confused it would be better if you can explain this with help of simple example

Comment: Also can you tell how come up with solution? I know 2520 is LCM of {1,2,3...,9} and why you are building tables for Y and Z?